# Org quota plan change not working - pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to change the quota of an Organization using

```
cf curl /v2/organizations/MY-ORGANIZATION-GUID -X 'PUT' -d "{\"quota_definition_guid\":\"NEW-QUOTA-PLAN-GUID\"}"
```

The execution was successful, but the Org quota plan has not actually changed. could someone please help.

Comment: Are you running this as the admin user? Any particular reason you are not using `cf update-quota`? https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/quota-plans.html#modify